# Google CloudSQL 2nd Generation create Function not working

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

For a Google CloudSQL 2nd generation instance, with Failover replication was enabled. After that when tried to import the database it is not allowing to create the procedure. Receiving below error.

> Error Code: 1419. You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary
>   logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Is it true that CloudSQL with failover will not support function ?

Sample execute query

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION `stutzen`(amount INT) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE charges FLOAT DEFAULT 1.0;
    SELECT valuesettings INTO charges FROM dreamer_tbl WHERE namesettings='stutzen.co';
    RETURN FLOOR((amount / 100) * charges) ;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud SQL support both, stored procedures and functions.

In your case the problem seems to be that you're trying to import a sql file that has some kind of routine that needs the SUPER privilege, and this is not permitted.

Comment: Where did you find that information? To my knowledge, User Defined Functions are not supported, see here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#differences

Comment: Hi @MarkVincze, you're right, cloud sql supports Stored Procedures and Funcions but does not support User Defined Functions.

What I wanted to say is that the Arvindwill function could be written as a function (therefore it was not necessary to write it as a stored).

Thanks for the correction, I will edit the answer. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You just need to set 'log_bin_trust_function_creators' to ON

To do it, open https://console.cloud.google.com

Select SQL

Select your instance

Select EDIT

DB signals

Add:
log_bin_trust_function_creators on

general_log on

SAVE

Answer (score 2):

You should run:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags
log_bin_trust_function_creators=ON
```

as mentioned [here](http://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/3eb6aDX62QI)

Answer (score 1):

That is not a Stored Procedure, that is a User Defined Function. 
You would need to rewrite this UDF as a Stored Procedure, which would work.

Comment: So Google Cloud SQL wont support User Defined Function?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the  SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators, which should allow creating functions without the SUPER privilege but setting that variable is also not allowed in Cloud SQL. It needs SUPER privilege for setting it.

Comment: you should set it from google settings interface of your cloudsql instance. they have specific set of variables allowed to be changed.